# How do I cache an object loaded through SOAP from a third party that I use in forms?

Tags: caching

I am loading and object that I use to populate a form. Then on form submit I return some of the fields through SOAP back to the third party. On submit the form building function gets called and loads the object then the submit function gets called and loads the object again. How do I cache the object so that it is only loaded once but available to both or more function to act on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers so far a very good. There is an additional method which is worth noting. static caching.

there a few places in Drupal core which use static caching and there is even a small api to support it in D7. the `static` keyword in PHP is a scope which is local to a function but remains between function calls.

So if you have a method to load your SOAP object you can set it as a static variable in the loading method

```
function my_loader($id) {
  // Initialize a static variable.
  static $loaded_items = array();
  // Check to see if object with $id has been loaded
  if (!is_set($loaded_items[$id]) P
    // code to load $soap_object;
    $loaded_items[$id] = $soap_object;
  }
  // Return the item 
  return $loaded_items[$id];
}
```

You can see it in action in Drupal core in [_menu_build_tree()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/_menu_build_tree/7). This only lasts for the duration of a request, but it can be handy with a framework where you are not sure when, or how many times a loader may be called.

**protips**

```
$trees = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
```

The [`drupal_static()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) method allows for static variables to be accessible from everywhere. This stops every function which declares static variables from having a clear flag. So if you save your soap object you can clear the static cache.

The `__FUNCTION__` magic word is the name of the function currently being executed.

The `&` before the function passes the return value by reference so that changes to $trees will be changed in the static variable in the function `drupal_static()`

Comment: Might be worth noting that if you use Eugene's approach (cache_get/set) it implements static caching, so you don't need to.

Comment: Although drupal_static is cool for per request caching, I am curious if this keeps values for entire form submission process.

Comment: @andy I am not sure if it does, it looks like it caches the cache controlling object statically but not the cache items themselves. I'm not sure if cache clear all would work well if it did.

Comment: @stefgosselin it depends on the process. Your method is probably best for that as you can guarantee that it will remain with the form, were as static caching will have to call soap service again if validation fails for example.

Comment: @JeremyFrench thanks for checking :) I'd read it recently in The Definitive Guide - it says _Drupal's caching functions take care of static caching for you, which is nice... when the data is fetched from the cache with a database query, it doesn't repeat this query during a page request. (See `api.drupal.org/_cache_get_object` which is called by `cache_get()`.)_ However my inspection of `_cache_get_object()` leads me to agree with you - it's the cache controller that's cached(!). Neither does DrupalDatabaseCache::getMultiple() statically cache AFAICT.

Answer (score 4):

Would it not be possible for you to simply pass off the data you need in fields of `#type => value`? These are passed safely behind the scene through the entire form submission process, acting in a sense as the cache you are striving for.  Consider the following simplistic example :

```
$form['soap_data_email'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => $soap_data_email);
$form['soap_data_name'] =  array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => $soap_data_name);
```

After submission, all your soap object's values would be available in the validation and submit callbacks of your form through the usual `$form_state['values']['soap_data_email']` and   `$form_state['values']['soap_data_name']` array.

If you have many variables this could all be factorised to be more efficient, but this should give you the basic idea.

This is the simplest way I can think of that lets you cache your data all across the form validation and submission process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have cache that will be accessible not only in one form, but all over the site - you can use [Drupal Cache API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/7)

Here is example for your case.

While creating form you save object in cache:

```
cache_set('my-variable_name', $object);
```

Then on submit handler you can load object from cache:

```
$object = cache_get('my-variable_name');
```